# Change password after changing password format in aspnet membership

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership, password-protection

I am using [aspnet membership](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) provider and by default HASHED password format were being used behind the scene and recently i got that password retrieval is not possible using that format. so i need to change password format to CLEAR OR ENCRYPTED however after doing this

is there any possible way to change password of existing data through database? OR i need to delete all records and start to create from scratch?

Also how one can handle situation where need to change password format from CLEAR to ENCRYPTED?

Comment: Are you aware of the security implications of what you're asking?

Comment: Why would you need their password?

Comment: @billinkc Yes i am aware of that. however i am in development stage as of now that's why i needed this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will not be able to decrypt a hashed password.  Hashing is by definition one-way. The two-way option available is the encrypt option, or clear.

The main function of hashing a password is for one-way encryption. Even internally when values are compared they are compared as hashed values.

[OK, technically one *could* decrypt a hashed value, but this enters into the realm of hackers, rainbow tables, salt values, and I do not think you wish to go there]

For more please [see here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe/)